# How to calculate c(B|A) and c(A|B) in this particular python problem

Tags: python, logic, calculation

Question:

```
We now calculate the synchronization between all possible pairs of rows
in the matrix. Given two lists A and B, each of N values 0 or 1, and a value tau
between zero and N, we define the synchronization index between A and B as:
       0.5 * (c(B|A) + c(A|B))
Sync = -----------------------
          sqrt(m(A)*m(B))
Where:
    - c(B|A) is the number of times an accent of B is preceded by an accent of A
      within a distance <= tau
    - c(A|B) is the number of times an accent of A is preceded by an accent of B
       within a distance <= tau
    - m(A) is the number of accents in A
    - m(B) is the number of accents in B
and where, remember, a value of 1 in A or B represents an accent
NOTA: if m(A) == 0 o m(B) == 0 then we assume zero Sync
For example, given the two sequences and value of tau:
    - A = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
    - B = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
    - tau = 3
we will obtain:
    - c(B|A) = 1, as only the third accent in B (position 4) is preceded in A by a
    accent within 3 positions (in this case the 1 in A has the same position
    as the 1 in B)
    - c(A|B) = 2, as both accents of A are preceded in B by two accents within
    3 positions
    - m(A) = 2
    - m(B) = 3
    - Sync = 0.5 × (1 + 2) / sqrt(2×3) = 0.6123724356957946
```

**[How is c(B|A) and/or c(A|B) calculated please explain me]**

[accent is 1 so third accent means the third "1" in the list (so third accent for B means i.e.third "1" in list B i.e position 4 (B[4]==third accent))

I tried to understand how it is calculated but I got very confused

Answer (score 0):

Not very well worded question, I agree.

"A has an accent" just means that `A[i]` is one.  `m(A) = 3` and `m(B) = 2` since there are three 1s in A, and two 1s in B.

`m(A|B)` means the number of times that there is an 1 is A and in the corresponding array B, there is a 1 either at that position or at one of the three previous positions.  If you look at both 1's in array A, there is a 1 in B either at the same position or in one of the three immediately previous positions.

Likewise for B.  Neither of the first two 1s in B has a corresponding 1 in A.

---

Note that it seemed like you were asking what the question meant.  I hope I explained it to you.  If you were asking for us to write your code for you, sorry, that's not what we do.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I needed an Explanation and yours, truly helped me